# Extract Alberta (Canada) postal code through regular expressions in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract postal codes of Alberta (Canada) region from an address string.

For example:

```
 addr = '12345-67 Ave, Edmonton, AB T1A 2B3, Canada'
```

Should extract `T1A 2B3`.

The regular expression to match the postal code is `[T]\d[A-Z] *\d[A-Z]\d`. However, I do not know that given an entire address, how can I extract only the postal code? I guess it has to do something with backreferences `()` but I cannot figure it out.

How can I achieve this in Python?

Comment: use a capture group: `(T\d[A-Z] \d[A-Z]\d)`. backreferences use capture groups, but calling the `()` backreferences is wrong.

Comment: @DSM: It's an Alberta postal code (like I mentioned in the question)

Comment: @WaqarHameed: you had it backwards-- 1A != A1.

Comment: @MarcB: That's precisely what I wanted to know how to do.

Comment: The internet is a magnificent place. I am trying to do the **exact** same thing AND I am doing it for Alberta Postal codes. (Though, I am looking at Calgary homes but let's not ruin the magic;). Thanks @MuhammadWaqar for asking this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extracting just the substring that matched the regexp is easy enough:

```
test = re.compile(r'[T]\d[A-Z] *\d[A-Z]\d')
addr = '12345-67 Ave, Edmonton, AB T1A 2B3, Canada'
test.search(addr).group()
```

`test.search` will return a match object, which has all kinds of stuff you can extract.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Peter's Answer here is how you can do it for some more postal codes:

US:

```
addr= 'Statue of liberty, New York, NY 10004, USA'
test = re.compile(r'\d{5}') 
test.search(addr).group()
```

UK:

```
addr= 'Olympic Park, Montfichet Rd, London E20 1EJ, United Kingdom'
test = re.compile(r'[A-Z]\d\d\s\d[A-Z]\d')
```

Canada:

```
addr= 'Toronto City Hall, 100 Queen St W, Toronto, ON M5H 2N2'
test = re.compile(r'[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\s\d[A-Z]\d')
```

`[A-Z]` Matches any uppercase letter in range A-Z

`[a-zA-Z]` Matches any uppercase letter in range A-Z (case insensitive)

`\d` matches any digit

`\d{n}` matches any occurrence of n digits

`\s` matches any whitespace character

You can also use [Regex101](https://regex101.com/), which is a very helpful tool for testing Regexes.